# How can I fix the 'IProgress not found' in zeppelin

Tags: python, apache-zeppelin

I install the Zeppelin0.10.1 and docker run to use the notebook, when I run these code, return a Error
ImportError: IProgress not found. Please update jupyter and ipywidgets. See https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html

Then I try to run `pip install jupyter`, but it's helpness.
The python is 3.7
Thanks.

```
    %python.ipython
    %matplotlib inline
    import torchvision
    import torchvision.transforms as transforms
    
    transform = transforms.Compose(
        [transforms.ToTensor(),
         transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
    cifar_train = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,download=True, transform=transform)
```

/opt/conda/envs/python_3_with_R/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tqdm/notebook.py in status_printer(_, total, desc, ncols)
114         if IProgress is None:  # #187 #451 #558 #872
115             raise ImportError(
--> 116                 "IProgress not found. Please update jupyter and ipywidgets."
117                 " See [https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable"](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable%22)
118                 "/user_install.html")